# Cannot find module 'pinia/dist/pinia.mjs' when using run dev

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

I setup Pinia on top of fresh Nuxt3 app and start dev server, with exactly these commands in order:

```
npx nuxi init nuxt-app
cd nuxt-app
npm install
npm install @pinia/nuxt
npm run dev
```

Dev server runs without any problem. Then, i put this line of code into "nuxt.config.ts";

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ["@pinia/nuxt"],
});
```

And, when I again try to connect to dev server, it gives me this error message in terminal:

```
 ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot find module 'pinia/dist/pinia.mjs'                                                                     12:03:55
Require stack:
- C:\Users\user\Documents\github2\nuxt-app\index.js
```

Comment: Can you try that one? https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/1542#issuecomment-1238820465

Comment: @kissu thank you, this works. I've seen this one but it felt not the best way to init Pinia, because Pinia's nuxt3 setup page doesn't mention this. But it turns out there's no any other way actually. This is a big mess to take energy of a junior dev so i'll give the info i took from every doc-forum in the bottom message

Comment: What do you mean by "init pinia"? I can recommend giving a try to yarn too, works better for me.

Comment: @kissu A good finding. As much as I'd like to stick to default pm, I always end up using yarn, just because it works where npm fails

Comment: @EstusFlask yeah, for me it's usually PNPM > yarn > npm (PNPM being the best). It works nicely, better output and you don't have to mess up with peerDeps or related stuff just getting into your way.

Comment: @kissu I wasn't able to handle this problem with yarn too. Nvm thank you so much. I wrote everything about this unnecessary challenge that i've gained experience throughout the week

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/1542#issuecomment-1238820465), there is an issue with NPM not doing it's job properly, here is how you can solve it:

```bash
npm i pinia -f
```

Comment: this works. forcing it can lead to further conflicts or package problems, but looks like it's the only working way for now.

Comment: What about production server?

Comment: If you run `npm i pinia -f` locally, I'm pretty sure some of your files may change, like the `package-lock.json` or alike. In production, your `node_modules` are always wiped, if it's not the case you should probably run a cache reset of some sort (depends where you do host your app). @kanuos

Comment: How can this still be necessary today? Is this something the pinia project could work around?

Comment: @katerlouis there is probably a Github issue open for that one.

Answer (score 28):

As I know this is a bug that will be fixed someday. Until then you can put

```js
alias: {
  pinia: "/node_modules/@pinia/nuxt/node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs"
},
```

in your `nuxt.config.ts` and it will work.

Found from this [VueSchool lesson on Pinia](https://vueschool.io/lessons/global-state-management-with-pinia).

Comment: Got an official source for that bug?

Comment: No. I found it in video lesson here: https://vueschool.io/lessons/global-state-management-with-pinia and it works for me.

Comment: Oh, I don't have a paid subscription but it's a legit link and a nice source indeed!

Comment: you may have to surround key pinia with quotes

    alias: {
        'pinia': "/node_modules/@pinia/nuxt/node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs"
    },

Comment: still not fixed in feb 2023 :(

Comment: @katerlouis at least the fix is simple.

Comment: this is still the fix in 2024, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I run into this a bit with fresh Nuxt 3 projects after installing `@pinia/nuxt`. The following has always worked for me.

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder.
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` file.
3. Make sure Pinia is the last item in the modules array `modules: ['a', 'b', 'c', '@pinia/nuxt'],`
4. Do a fresh `npm install`.

There should be no need to install `pinia` separately, having `@pinia/nuxt` should be enough.

Comment: This is the correct answer!
I tried:
1. npm install pinia -f - No joy
2 Aliasing pinia - still no joy
3. yarn (a full refresh before trying yarn) - same error
4. this answer - it works!

I wish I had tried this first

Answer (score 2):

You need to install pinia itself.

```
npm i pinia
```

But you might need to add the following line to your `package.json` file before running the above command.

```
"overrides": {
    "vue": "latest"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please install using Yarn `yarn add @pinia/nuxt` instead of npm.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error `ERROR Cannot find module 'pinia/dist/pinia.mjs'` when using the following dependencies in my Nuxt project:

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "nuxt": "^3.9.0",
    "nuxt-primevue": "^0.2.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.14",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primevue": "^3.46.0"
  }
```

The solution was to ignore the Nuxt documentation and use the documentation from [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html#installation) which suggests the following steps:

1. Install dependency:
   `npm install pinia @pinia/nuxt`
2. Add module in nuxt.config.ts

```js
// Nuxt 3
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],
})
```